# How can I test the latest Polymer lib when it requires an older SDK?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I wanted to give the latest Dart Polymer lib a spin, so I updated the pubspec file and ran a pub install. However, the install fails with the following message:

> Pub install failed, [1] Resolving dependencies.........
>
> Package polymer requires SDK version >=0.8.1+1 but the current SDK is
> 0.7.6+4.r28108

Is it somehow possible to use the latest Polymer version via pubspec, or do I need to build the SDK myself from the sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/ has links to the bleeding edge, continuous build `DartEditor`

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/darteditor-win32-32.zip
https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/darteditor-win32-64.zip
```

As of today, you should be able to upgrade 0.8.1.2 if you go to `Help > About Dart Editor`.

It seems pretty common that the libraries update a day or two before the SDK, so normally when I run into this problem I put in the pubspec something like the following until I can update the SDK:

```
dependencies:
  polymer: "< 8.0.0"
```